# Merge to different LiveData List into a unique List

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I want to merge to different `LiveData<List<Element>>` into one, I have thought that `MediatorLiveData<List<Element>>` would be a great option, but I´m not sure about it because onChange is called with the full List so I can´t add only the new elements, how can I achieve add only the new data.
My code:

```
val localData = repository.getAllElementsFromDatabase()
val internetData = MutableLiveData<List<Element>>()

val allData = MediatorLiveData<List<Element>>()

init {
    internetData.postValue(repository.getAllElementsFromInternet())
    allData.addSource(localData){
        if (allData.value==null) allData.value = it
        else for (elem in it!!) allData.value.add(elem)
    }
    allData.addSource(internetData){
        if (allData.value==null) allData.value = it
        else for (elem in it!!) allData.value.add(elem)
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: The list you provide through LiveData should generally be **immutable**. If you want to emit new items, you should emit a new list.